# Vigenere Cipher not encoding properly

Tags: haskell, recursion

```
calcAlphaPos :: Char -> Int
calcAlphaPos a 
    | (a `elem` ['a'..'z']) = ord(a) - ord('a')
    | (a `elem` ['A'..'Z']) = ord(a) - ord('A') 
    | otherwise = 0

calcOffset :: String -> Int -> Int
calcOffset word pos = calcAlphaPos (word !! (pos `mod` (length word)))
          
encodex :: Int -> Char -> Char
encodex offset ch
    | (ch `elem` ['a'..'z']) = chr ((((ord ch - ord ('a')) + offset + 26) `mod` 26) + ord('a'))
    | (ch `elem` ['A'..'Z']) = chr ((((ord ch - ord ('A')) + offset + 26) `mod` 26) + ord('A'))
    | otherwise = ch

encode :: String -> String -> Int -> String
encode _ [] _ = "...End of message"
encode [] _ _ = "Invalid decoder word!"
encode word (x:xs) y
    | (word !! wordpos) `elem` ['a'..'z'] = [encodex (calcOffset word y) x] ++ encode word xs (y+1)
    | (word !! wordpos) `elem` ['A'..'Z'] = [encodex (calcOffset word y) x] ++ encode word xs (y+1)
    | otherwise = [x] ++ encode word xs y
     where wordpos = y `mod` length word
```

1. encode "ALLY" "MEET AT DAWN" 0

   ```
   should produce MPPR AE OYWY but produces MPPR LE DLHL

   note "ALLY" provides offset of 0, 11, 11, 24
   MEET =                 [12,  4,  4, 19]
   MPPR =                 [12, 15, 15, 17] <-- 43 - 26 = 17
   ```

I'm learning haskell and have been trying to figure out what I am doing wrong in regards
to the Vegenere cipher.  When I don't use spaces in the message the cipher works but I can't
seem to figure out how to get it to work when spaces are included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is embarassing but what I did wrong is that I checked each letter in the key to see if it had a special character rather than checking each character in the message.  I replaced encode with this:

```
encode :: String -> String -> Int -> String
encode _ [] _ = "...End of message"
encode [] _ _ = "Invalid decoder word!"
encode word (x:xs) y
    | x `elem` ['a'..'z'] = [encodex (calcOffset word y) x] ++ encode word xs (y+1)
    | x `elem` ['A'..'Z'] = [encodex (calcOffset word y) x] ++ encode word xs (y+1)
    | otherwise = [x] ++ encode word xs y
    where wordpos = y `mod` length word
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is, as you have noticed, that your code does not account for spaces. You want something like this:

```
       [key] ALLY AL LYAL
 [plaintext] MEET AT DAWN
[ciphertext] MPPR AE OYWY
```

But instead, your code is doing this:

```
       [key] ALLYALLYALLY
 [plaintext] MEET AT DAWN
[ciphertext] MPPR LE DLHL
```

To fix this, the simplest method is probably to just skip spaces when encoding: if the current character is a space, then ignore it and go on to the next character, else encode the current character as normal.

Comment: But I thought that the line   "otherwise = [x] ++ encode word  xs  y" took that into account!

Comment: In the   "| otherwise = [x] ++ encode word xs y"    clause  I tried "otherwise = "...Message" but my cipher ignores that clause.  Is there something about guards or pattern matching that causes this?

Comment: @PhilipStephens The issue is in your recursive call. You pattern-match on your key as being `(x:xs)`, so `xs` refers to everything _except_ for the first character of your key; thus you are still skipping a letter of the key when you reach a space. The correct guard clause would be `| otherwise = [x] ++ encode word (x:xs) y`, ensuring you still retain the first character of the key for the next letter of the plaintext.